# Symfony - Store images incoming from requests

Tags: php, symfony

I am making an app with a feature of adding posts. Every post have the possibility to contain an image. My main problem is the thing I don't know how to store the images. I know I can create a seperate folder named for example "private" but the thing is it should have some structure to not put all images together. I would like to avoid having thousands of images in one folder. I've seen somewhere that people make a structure of folders then somehow decide where each image should be stored (for example by original file name). This looks something like this:

```
private:
    15:
       23:
          image_file.jpg
       88:
          image_file2.jpg
    13:
       48:
          image_file3.jpg
```

Is there a way to do this kind of file structure in Symfony? The only solution that I have in my mind is somehow transforming filenames into numbers then using modulo. But I don't think it is a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply incorporate your Post ID into path:

```php
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Entity\Post;

class ArticleAdminController extends BaseController
{
    public function temporaryUploadAction(Request $request, Post $post, string $projectDir)
    {
        /** @var UploadedFile $uploadedFile */
        $uploadedFile = $request->files->get('image');
        $uploadedFile->move("{$projectDir}/private/{$post->getId()}");
    }
}
```

Comment: This way i would achieve only one step high folder structure and this wouldn't help because the number of folders would be the same as the number of files. I don't see any benefits from this solution. I would like to achieve way less amount of folders than the amount of files stored in them.

Comment: @Darpek Alternative is sorting files by date, by user, by type, etc. But you got the idea: incorporate some sorting content into path to have files sorted into separate folders

Comment: Is there a better way to solve this problem? I thought there should be some standard for doing this kind of things.

Comment: @Darpek _You_ tell me what all these numbers inside your example means.

Comment: @Darpek Because there is nothing wrong about storing all images in one folder

Comment: There is no specific meaning of those numbers. I just heard once that Symfony has build feature to store files in similar way.  If there is no such thing, I will do as you said.